# TextRenderer. How to render text multiline with endellipsis?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-styles

How i can render text like this(simple listview)?

[image: default ListView render]

Trying the code like this renders no ellipsis:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(_listGraphics,
                   anItem.Text, GetItemFont(anItem),
                   textRec,
                   Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ControlText),
                   TextFormatFlags.Top| TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis|
                   TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
```

if I remove `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak` then the text becomes single line.

Its to manual hot track the items while Drag-n-drop over them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Hans taught me, there is a flag for that by including the TextBoxControl flag:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, myString, this.Font,
                      textRec, Color.Black, Color.Empty,
                      TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                      TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl |
                      TextFormatFlags.WordBreak |
                      TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);
```

Comment: However, it uses different approach to render the text and i still cant get the exact copy of text. For example : gap between "ll" rendered new way a bit bigger and all text looks wider (

Comment: @DimDim DrawString had a lot of issues, which was why Microsoft fixed a lot of things with TextRenderer.  Unfortunately, TextRenderer has some limitations, too.  There is always WPF to consider, for another answer.

Comment: Just use TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl instead. Don't hurt me :)

Comment: @HansPassant The information by the [TextFormatFlags Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) document is sparse on the subject to say the least.  As always, danke schön.

Comment: Yes, that's close :)  Dank je between friends or growing up in the 1970s.  Definitely je.